# Convert viewbag to javascript array

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, arrays, viewbag

I want to get the data from the ViewBag.mytags to a Javascript array, but I was not able to avhice this

```
$(function () {
    var sampleTags = new Array();
    var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.mytags));
    for(var i =0; i<array.length;i++){
        sampleTags[i] = array[i];
    }  
    $('#singleFieldTags').tagit({
        availableTags: sampleTags,
        singleField: true,
        singleFieldNode: $('#mySingleField')
    });
}
```

This is  my controller

```
ViewBag.mytags = mp3.TagSuggestion();
```

This is my Models

```
public IQueryable<string> TagSuggestion() 
{ 

    IQueryable<string> tabs = from s in db.tblTags select s.Title; 

    return tabs; 

}
```

Comment: Have you given ajax a try? In mvc you can use a controller action method that returns json data like: public JsonResult ActionName(){ return Json("Data", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); }. You may also look at the following post: http://www.cleancode.co.nz/blog/739/ajax-aspnet-mvc-3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please follow these step

```
public IList<string> TagSuggestion() 
{ 
    IQueryable<string> tabs = from s in db.tblTags select s.Title; 
    return tabs.toList(); 
}
```

Inside MVC Contoller :

```
ViewBag.mytags = mp3.TagSuggestion().toList();
```

In view:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var sampleTags = new Array();
        var array = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@ViewBag.mytags));
        for(var i =0; i<array.length;i++){
            sampleTags[i] = array[i];
        }  

        $('#singleFieldTags').tagit({
            availableTags: sampleTags,
            singleField: true,
            singleFieldNode: $('#mySingleField')
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Pushpendra: The code you posted, should be written in <script></script> tags? If so then how could you use server variable (ViewBag) on client script. This is not efficient solution.

Comment: point one is not inside the script. It should inside the controller. and second point should be inside the script.

Comment: @Pushpendra: Javascript does not contain ArrayList type, How I will write a c sharp inside script?

Comment: Please check it the code which i have editted. now it is tested.

Comment: @Pushpendra:it is same to my code above and, if it worked that way I will not ask my question.

Comment: but please change the ViewBag.mytags = mp3.TagSuggestion(); to ViewBag.mytags = mp3.TagSuggestion().toList(); It is working on my system. I have checked and give you finally.